# Using an actor with persistence for a shopping cart so every visitor will have their own actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

If I have an actor to represent a shopping cart:

```
class ShoppingCartActor extends PersistentActor with ActorLogging {
   override def persistenceId: String = "shopping-cart-actor"

   override def receiveCommand: Receive = ???
   override def receiveRecover: Receive = ???
}

val system = ActorSystem("PersistenceActors")

for(i <- 1 to 100) {
  val carts = system.actorOf(Props[ShoppingCartActor], s"shopping-cart-actor-$i"
}
```

If I create a new shopping cart actor for every visitor to a ecommerce store, will all event messages be stored in the same journal/table in the storage engine? e.g. postgres or cassandra

If it is the same journal/table, how does it reload the events for the correct shopping cart actor since each visitor/customer will have their own shopping cart actor.

Answer (score 1):

The `persistenceId` should be unique per `PersistentActor`.  That is how persistence retrieves the events per specific actor (in postgres or cassandra it will be stored in its own column).  So you'd want something like

```
class ShoppingCartActor(cartNum: Int) extends PersistentActor with ActorLogging {
  override def persistenceId: String = s"shopping-cart:$cartNum"

  override def receiveCommand: Receive = ???
  override def receiveRecover: Receive = ???
}

object ShoppingCartActor {
  def props(cartId: String): Props[ShoppingCartActor] =
    Props(new ShoppingCartActor(cartId))
}
```

And then:

```
val system = ActorSystem(???)

val carts = (1 to 100).map { cartNum =>
  cartNum -> system.actorOf(ShoppingCartActor.props(cartNum), s"shopping-cart-actor-$i")
}.toMap
```

EDIT to clarify:

The Postgres schema for the event journal is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS journal (
  ordering BIGSERIAL,
  persistence_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  sequence_number BIGINT NOT NULL,
  deleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,
  tags VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  message BYTEA NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(persistence_id, sequence_number)
)
```

i.e. each event is one row in the journal table with a column corresponding to the `persistenceId`.  Akka Persistence Cassandra also uses a single journal table.

Comment: Yes but then won't there be so many "tables" in the data store?  There could be millions of shopping carts eventually... so there would be millions of journal tables?  (assuming I don't purge them)

Comment: For the persistence backends I'm aware of which use tables (e.g. JDBC, Cassandra), all events get written to one table.